# How do I limit the number of returned records in a Taleo Client Connect query?

Tags: taleo, taleo-connect-client

I know that it is possible to do this when I do a SQ-XML call to the api with the maxrecordcount attribute, ie:

```
   <ns:attributes>
    <ns:entry>
     <ns:key>maxrecordcount</ns:key>
     <ns:value>2</ns:value>
    </ns:entry>
   </ns:attributes>
```

However, the TCC only lets you change what's in the query tag, not the attributes one.

Is there any way to accomplish the equivalent of LIMIT with the TCC?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pageindex and Paging Size options in Advanced parameters of sq file. look at the example in the image

[image: TCC Paging example]

Comment: @BuddyBob: The "link" is a image... A terrible one (since it seems to be a photo instead of a screenshot) but definitely not link only.